# Matlab and excel timestamp with datenum

Tags: matlab, timestamp

At the moment I am using xlsread to open a set of data that I have in excel with given timestamps. But when these values are placed in matlab it changes the formatting of the timestamp.
In excel it is:
dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM

but when it puts it into matlab it changes it to

mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM

which ruins my other code. I have tried using formatIn and specifying it, but then it returns an error if no value for midnight is given.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What code do you use? In what format do you have those timestamps in Matlab? Cell array of strings?

Comment: Yeah, was a cell array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) and [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) to convert the format to what you want. In the following example I'm assuming your timestamps are contained in a cell array of strings, but it also works if it's a char matrix:

```
>> timestamps = {'08/25/2014 13:14'; '08/26/2014 14:15'} %// mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM
>> result = datestr(datenum(timestamps, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM'), 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM')
result =
25/08/2014 13:14
26/08/2014 14:15
```

Comment: If you want to enforce a standard date format, I would recommend this method. However if the excel contains an unusual date format and that is required, consider just using the date representation directly.

Comment: Thats what I originally had, specify the format directly using datenum but it doesn't like it when no HH:MM is given. Matlab imports 00:00 being midnight as a blank which is simply the default.

It chucks an error because of this. Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: It should default to 0 if no value is given but my code is not doing this. :/

Comment: So when I go
>> datenum('1/01/2011', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM')
It throws an error instead of defaulting to zero like it should.

Answer (score 0):

What Luis recommended should help you to get any format that you like. However there is something important to realize here:

Excel does not 'have' the date in your format. It has the date stored as a number like 123546.123 and presents it to you in a certain way.

If you want to get the date in exactly the way that excel presents it, the trick is to avoid importing the relevant column as a date, but just import it as text instead.

How to do this depends on your import method, but it should not be very hard.